# Can't Write to Arm Coprocessor Register on Qemu-Arm

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, qemu, osdev

I'm emulating arm1176jzf-s on qemu-system-arm. Because I'm trying to develop a simple barebones operating system for raspberry pi zero, for that I'm using a boot code from wiki.osdev.org to jump to c code. Inside it, I'm trying to write some data to a coprocessor register, "coprocessor control access register" to be exact. I can read as fine but when I try to write, value doesn't change. Code is something like this:

```
    uint32_t dest = 0, tmp = 0;
   /* Read the coprocessor access control register. */
    __asm ("mrc p15, 0, %[dst], c1, c0, 2"
          : [dst] "=r" (dst));

    log_uint(dst, 'h');
    log_uint(dst, 'b');

   /* Enable access for domain control access register.
     Modifies dst to be 0xC0000040. */
    SETBIT(dst, 6);

    log_uint(dst, 'h');
    log_uint(dst, 'b');

    /* Write the changed value. */
    __asm ("mcr p15, 0, %[dst], c1, c0, 2"
          :
          : [dst] "r" (dst));

    /* Read the coprocessor access control register. */
    __asm ("mrc p15, 0, %[tmp], c1, c0, 2"
          : [tmp] "=r" (tmp));

    log_uint(tmp, 'h');
    log_uint(tmp, 'b');
```

log_uint, prints an integer in binary or hexadecimal form using uart.

Outputs follow as:

```
C0000000
11000000000000000000000000000000
C0000040
11000000000000000000000001000000
C0000000
11000000000000000000000000000000
```

According to technical reference manual of the processor: **You must perform an Instruction Memory Barrier (IMB) sequence immediately after an update of the Coprocessor Access Control Register**.
I've tried many combinations of *Data Synchronization Barrier* operation and *Flush* operations of *Prefetch Buffer* together. But that didn't work so I'm not sure how to do this IMB sequence, and I wasn't able to find it.

But one more thing that bugs me is that, according to the processor manual, coprocessor access control register has to have the reset value **0x00000000**, but I read **0xC0000000**.

In kernel, before this code, I just initialize uart, and nothing else, so everything should be at reset value.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to set the CPACR bits corresponding to coprocessor 4. That doesn't exist in QEMU's 1176 CPU, so the CPACR bits for it are RAZ/WI. I'm not sure what you're trying to do this for -- the comment mentions a "domain control access register", but the 1176 domain access control register (DACR) is in cp15, not cp4. If the code you're copying really needs to access a "coprocessor 4" then you'll need to modify it to not do that, because whatever it is, QEMU doesn't implement it.

The always-1 bits in the top bits are strictly speaking a QEMU bug, but they're harmless -- we're implementing "ASEDIS and D32DIS are RAO if the CPU doesn't have Neon or D16-D31" for all v7 cores, but earlier ones like the 1176 didn't have those fields and the bits should really read as zero.